# function for copy action in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a simple but at the same time tricky problem. I need to copy the formula of the referenced cell and not the value itself. Such formula would perform exactly the same action as Ctr + C and Ctr + V via reference. The goal is extract the formula line itself with relative reference.

For example in this picture 1.5 is calculated via formula as an average of 1 and 2. I would like to code a reference to the cell with value 1.5 in such way that the formula is copied and the value in the yellow cell is returned at 3.5  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHmW9.png)

[image]

Thanks in advance!
Andrew

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: What about copy and paste special as formula? Do you tried paste special

Comment: I don't think that is possbile with formula. It could be possible with VBA UDF.

Answer (score 0):

You could record a macro with a Keyboard Shortcut of `Ctrl+Shift+V` and add the below code to it.

There's still plenty that could go wrong though:- the clipboard needs something copied into it first, it will only work on a single cell.

```
Sub PasteMyFormula()
'
' PasteMyFormula Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+V
'

    ActiveSheet.Paste
    With Selection
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Formula = "'" & .Formula
    End With

End Sub
```

**Edit:**  Excel 2013 has a new fangled formula called [FormulaText](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/formulatext-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8) which appears to do it all.